# keep root div center to page when window size changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please refer below code

```
<div id="root">
<div id="child1">xxxx</div>
<div id="child2">yyyy</div>
</div>
```

css :

```
  #root
    {
        width:86%
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #root div
    {
        width: 50%;
        float:left; 
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

it will center the "root" div center to page.but some resolution is not aligned (i.e.centered)

so am checking the javascript/jquery code instead of using media query (since am using iE8 browser -media not supported)

```
<script type"text/javascript">

 if (window.screen.availWidth >= 1200 && window.screen.availWidth <= 1390  ) { 
$("#root").css("width","92%")

}
else
$("#root").css("width","86%")
</script>
```

but when browser window is resized , div content misaligned not centered to page. how can i manitain the div to center for all resolutions as well browser window changed ?

i dont know what percentage of width need to be set for each time  window is reszied.

How to resolve this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, need to use any `script` for keep in center, it is also done by CSS :

Here is [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/q88Vu/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in `.resize()` method:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
   if ($(this).width() >= 1200 && $(this).width() <= 1390  ) { 
      $("#root").css("width","92%");
   }else{
      $("#root").css("width","86%");
   }
}).resize();
```

---

Not sure but this might causing you issues:

```
#root
{
    width:86%  // <-------here you have a missing ';'
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: that time what width i need to set i dont know ? i knew window resize method am not aware of percentage of width

Comment: see "percentage of width" is calculated in pixels so do as you are doing, i mean if we do it with css meadia queried there we have to go for the device width in `px` so better to do with conditions in js as suggested above.

Comment: 92% and 86% just giving some manual values after aligned the content through developer tools but when window resizing how do i know what is the exact width i need to set to center?

Comment: `width:86%  // <-------here you have a missing ';'` for `#root`